# No of ways to arranging plants?

Tags: combinatorics

I want to find the no of ways of arranging four type plants in a row such that no two plants of same type are consecutive.
I am able to figure out the formula for two plants but struggling for plants>2.

> Example: $a=2,b=2,c=0,d=0$. 
>   
> Answer: $2,(abab,baba)$

Comment: So you have $n$ pairs of plants and want to put them in a row so that no two of a pair are next to each other?

Comment: @RossMillikan: No two of a kind should be next to each other. How many we have of each kind needs to be specified, I think.

Comment: there are four types of plants and each type will be >= 0

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have $n$ pairs of plants and want to put them in a row so that no two of a pair is next to each other, we can count $n=3$ by hand. We can decide to start with $ab$ and then multiply by $6$.  If we start with $aba$ we have to finish with $cbc$ for $1$ possibility. If we start with $abc$ we have $2$ choices for the next plant (not c), then two for the next and then $1$ for $4$ ways to finish.  The total of $5$ starting $ab$ gives $30$ for all two character starts.

I then put $2,30$ into OEIS and found [A114938](http://oeis.org/A114938)  which gives
Number of permutations of the multiset {1,1,2,2,....,n,n} with no two consecutive terms equal.
$0, 2, 30, 864, 39480, 2631600, 241133760, 29083420800, 4467125013120, 851371260364800, 197158144895712000, 54528028997584665600, 17752366094818747392000, 6720318485119046923315200, 2927066537906697348594432000, 1453437879238150456164433920000$  and the reference R. P. Stanley, Enumerative Combinatorics Volume I, Cambridge University Press, 1997. Chapter 2, Sieve Methods, Example 2.2.3, page 68